# How to display any part of the layout in fullscreen landscape mode on a button click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have fragments in a viewpager and in one of those fragments there is one child layout which contains a button and on that button click i have to display that layout in full screen and in landscape mode. What i am currently using is :

```
  requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

But the problem with above method is it changes the whole activity to landscape mode including the other fragments and when user swipes the other fragments are too getting displayed in landscape which i don't want. So what's the fix for this problem? Please suggest!

Comment: You can not set the orientation fragment only. There is no fix for that. yes but you can change the orientation when user swipe the other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change particular fragment orientation with above method, you need to design your layout in landscape mode as well, so whenever user click on that particular button show that landscape design, you can use some layout change animation during change of layout.

> Don't change your app orientation regularly, it may cause issue with
>   your data if you not following view model concept. And also changing  orientation simultaneous give bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I used

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

to prevent the activity to restart when the orientation is changed. Otherwise, the activity restarts and goes into the correct fragment and change the orientation again, repeat.

In the Fragment's `onResume()` method I call

> getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

and in it's `onPause()` I call

> getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your activity in which you want rotation

```
android:configchanges="orientation"
```

Override onConfigurationChanged method in activity and paste the following code. Make sure to get the fragment in which you want to rotate the activity. Its just a base code, You can add your logic as you like or you can modify it as you want.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        if (checkFragmentForRotation()) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }else{
            setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // otherwise lock in portrait
        }
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private boolean checkFragmentForRotation() {
        //find your fragment by tag or by any other means
        Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                <Tag of your fragment here>);

        return (fr != null && fr.isResumed() && fr.getClass().isInstance(<YourFragment>.class));
    }
```